# Permutation function which allows for repetitions

Tags: matrix, permutation

I want to permute a matrix based on some permutation cycle which is not known beforehand. A function searches through the matrix and returns the pair of indices $i,j$ of the first entry which equals some specific value. Now, I want to permute the matrix such that that column $j$ appears first in the matrix. I would use the function `Cycles[{{1,j}}]`, but it doesn't work if the index $j$ equals 1 (since I want to bring it to the first column).

Is there a way to create a general permutation function such that in the situation that $j=1$, it just returns the identity permutation (so it doesn't permute the matrix)?

Answer (score 2):

You want to exchange column `1` with column `j` of a matrix.
You can use `Part` to achieves this. Here is an example:

```
mat = Array[Subscript[a,  #1, #2] &, {3, 3}]
j = 3;
mat[[All, {j, 1}]] = mat[[All, {1, j}]];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Most importantly to the OP is that this works also for `j=1`.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher Does it not?

Comment: No, it does. I just meant to point this out once more. =)